# EDX - /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso: No space left on device (RuntimeError)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, edx

When doing 'vagrant up' for EDX fullstack with the Eucalyptus 2 open release, I get this error message -

`/tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso: No space left on device (RuntimeError)`

I'm running Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS

Also there is a report that the GuestAdditions versions don't match.
I know this host is not officially supported yet, but I do like pioneering =]

```
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.2.0
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.20
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
[default] GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.24) and guest (5.0.20) do not match.
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.2.0
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.20
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
The guest's platform ("linux") is currently not supported, will try generic Linux method...
```

I had remnants of another VirtualBox installation. After purging the other package, I get a different error - one I had before trying the newer version of VirtualBox. So Im not sure the original error is resolved.

This is the new error -

```
Installing the 'vagrant-hostsupdater' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:946:in `all=': undefined method `group_by' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I used a workaround to solve this issue before when I was working with the devstack.
I'll modify the file and try again.

More configuration info -

```
~$ dpkg -l | grep virtualbox
ii  unity-scope-virtualbox                      0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1                                 all          VirtualBox scope for Unity
ii  virtualbox                                  5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1                                amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-dkms                             5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1                                all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso              5.0.24-0ubuntu1.16.04.1                                     all          guest additions iso image for VirtualBox
ii  virtualbox-qt                               5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1                                amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface

~$ dpkg -l | grep vagrant
ii  vagrant                                     1.8.1+dfsg-1
```

** I've updated Vagrant to 1.8.5 now and it has resolved the "undefined method `group_by'"  but the space issue remains.
This is the latest output -

```
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'eucalyptus-fullstack-2016-09-01'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: fullstack_default_1473446522717_26289
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.2.0
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.20
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
[default] GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.24) and guest (5.0.20) do not match.
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.2.0
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.20
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
The guest's platform ("linux") is currently not supported, will try generic Linux method...
Copy iso file /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater] Checking for host entries
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater]   found entry for: 192.168.33.10 preview.localhost
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-scp-1.1.2/lib/net/scp.rb:392:in `await_response_state': scp: /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso: No space left on device (RuntimeError)
```

Disk space usage on host -

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs           717M  9.4M  708M   2% /run
/dev/sda2       910G   13G  851G   2% /
tmpfs           3.6G  172K  3.6G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  3.6M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           717M   44K  717M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Update -
I noticed that the space is not actually in use on the guest, but reserved I think...

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ ls -alh /empty 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69G Sep  1 11:45 /empty
```

Comment: It's not clear whether that message is about the host OS or the guest OS?  Can you show us the output of:  sudo du -sh /*

Comment: Thanks Ned, it was for the guest OS. Plenty of space on the host.

Comment: There were remnants of another VirtualBox installation.. I'm not sure I resolved the issue by removing... Im back to an older issue. I'll edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by removing everything except the boxes directory under "~/.vagrant.d".  And changed to "open-release/eucalyptus.1"

There must have been an old configuration item in there.

On another note, I got this error afterwards -

```
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater]   found entry for: 192.168.33.10 preview.localhost
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
Vagrant attempted to execute the capability 'configure_networks'
on the detect guest OS 'linux', but the guest doesn't
support that capability. This capability is required for your
configuration of Vagrant. Please either reconfigure Vagrant to
avoid this capability or fix the issue by creating the capability.
```

but resolved this by editing the Vagrant file -

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

to this -

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10", type: "dhcp", auto_config: false
```