# Vagrant share throwing "No space left on device" error

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-share

I am trying to share my vagrant using ssh. During the sharing process it creates a new virtual machine and trying to copy the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso file to it, but it throwing "**No space left on device (RuntimeError)**" exception. Because it is a new dynamic VM we don't have any control.The full trace of "**vagrant share --ssh**" is listed below.How to solve this issue ?

I allocated 100GB hard disk and 4 GB ram, but it is using only 2GB of HD.

**Solutions tried :**

[vagrant no space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746907/vagrant-no-space-left-on-device)

[EDX - /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso: No space left on device (RuntimeError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415081/edx-tmp-vboxguestadditions-iso-no-space-left-on-device-runtimeerror)

**Exception :**

```
Vagrant Share now defaults to using the `ngrok` driver.
The `classic` driver has been deprecated.

For more information about the `ngrok` driver, please
refer to the documentation:

  https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/

==> awsoi: Detecting network information for machine...
    awsoi: Local machine address: 127.0.0.1
    awsoi:  
    awsoi: Note: With the local address (127.0.0.1), Vagrant Share can only
    awsoi: share any ports you have forwarded. Assign an IP or address to your
    awsoi: machine to expose all TCP ports. Consult the documentation
    awsoi: for your provider ('virtualbox') for more information.
    awsoi:  
    awsoi: An HTTP port couldn't be detected! Since SSH is enabled, this is
    awsoi: not an error. If you want to share both SSH and HTTP, please set
    awsoi: an HTTP port with `--http`.
    awsoi:  
==> awsoi: Generating new SSH key...
    awsoi: Please enter a password to encrypt the key: 
    awsoi: Repeat the password to confirm: 
    awsoi: Inserting generated SSH key into machine...
    awsoi: Local HTTP port: disabled
    awsoi: Local HTTPS port: disabled
    awsoi: SSH Port: 2226
    awsoi: Port: 2226
    awsoi: Port: 23000
    awsoi: Port: 24500
    awsoi: Port: 25432
    awsoi: Port: 28080
==> awsoi: Creating Vagrant Share session...
    share: Importing base box 'hashicorp/vagrant-share'...
    share: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
    share: Setting the name of the VM: share-9451ce4c-ea4a-4a1b-ad73-2f2117705b16
    share: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    share: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    share: Adapter 1: nat
    share: Forwarding ports...
    share: 31338 (guest) => 65535 (host) (adapter 1)
    share: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
    share: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    share: Booting VM...
    share: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    share: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    share: SSH username: tc
    share: SSH auth method: password
    share: 
    share: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    share: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    share: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
    share: Machine booted and ready!
[share] No installation found.
The guest's platform ("tinycore") is currently not supported, will try generic Linux method...
Copy iso file /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
==> share: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> share: Destroying VM and associated drives...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp.rb:398:in `await_response_state': scp: /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso: No space left on device (RuntimeError)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp.rb:369:in `block (3 levels) in start_command'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:320:in `process'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:238:in `block in ev_preprocess'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:529:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:529:in `each_channel'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:238:in `ev_preprocess'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/event_loop.rb:99:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/event_loop.rb:99:in `ev_preprocess'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/event_loop.rb:27:in `process'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:216:in `process'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:178:in `block in loop'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:178:in `loop'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:178:in `loop'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp.rb:284:in `upload!'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:291:in `block in upload'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:684:in `block in scp_connect'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:332:in `connect'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:682:in `scp_connect'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:285:in `upload'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.14.2/lib/vagrant-vbguest/installers/base.rb:201:in `upload'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.14.2/lib/vagrant-vbguest/installers/linux.rb:64:in `install'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.14.2/lib/vagrant-vbguest/installer.rb:63:in `install'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.14.2/lib/vagrant-vbguest/machine.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in guest_additions_state'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/micromachine-2.0.0/lib/micromachine.rb:49:in `block in change'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/micromachine-2.0.0/lib/micromachine.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/micromachine-2.0.0/lib/micromachine.rb:49:in `change'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/micromachine-2.0.0/lib/micromachine.rb:23:in `trigger'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.14.2/lib/vagrant-vbguest/machine.rb:36:in `install'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.14.2/lib/vagrant-vbguest/machine.rb:25:in `run'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.14.2/lib/vagrant-vbguest/middleware.rb:25:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/wait_for_communicator.rb:71:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/boot.rb:18:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/sane_defaults.rb:38:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/set_hostname.rb:16:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/forward_ports.rb:31:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network_fix_ipv6.rb:41:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:122:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_network_interfaces.rb:26:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_settings.rb:18:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:87:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action_cleanup.rb:25:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:49:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-puppet-install-4.1.0/lib/vagrant-puppet-install/action/install_puppet.rb:20:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:23:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/match_mac_address.rb:19:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/discard_state.rb:15:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:74:in `import'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:13:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_clone_snapshot.rb:17:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/prepare_clone.rb:15:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:227:in `action_raw'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:202:in `block in action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:188:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:188:in `action'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-share-1.1.9/lib/vagrant-share/activate.rb:2379:in `block (2 levels) in start_share'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:554:in `block in with_ui'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:550:in `synchronize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:550:in `with_ui'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-share-1.1.9/lib/vagrant-share/activate.rb:2378:in `block in start_share'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:235:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:229:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:229:in `with_target_vms'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-share-1.1.9/lib/vagrant-share/activate.rb:2273:in `start_share'
    from /Users/santhoshkumar/.vagrant.d/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-share-1.1.9/lib/vagrant-share/activate.rb:2967:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:308:in `cli'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.6/bin/vagrant:138:in `<main>'
```

Comment: vagrant share wants to install VirtualBox Guest Additions software but you're running out of space on your VM. you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31747505/4296747 which covers how to extend your drive

Comment: Vagrant share dynamically creates a new VM and trying to install guest on that machine , not on my vagrant . Also guest is already installed on my VM.  I tried the above solution also but no luck.

Comment: where did you get that `vagrant share` creates a new VM ? run `vagrant share` if you did not create your VM and you get `The Vagrant environment you're attempting to share appears to
not be running. Please verify that it is running and try again.` `vagrant share` _is a feature that will allow you to share your running Vagrant environment_

Comment: Every time executing vagrant share --ssh command  in VM manager I saw a VM is created dynamically. In the above log itself we can see they are importing some VM box.

Comment: Same problem for me.. vagrant up works but vagrant share doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a valid bug, but here is a workaround for now:

`vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vbguest`

The problem is that `vagrant-vbguest` kicks in even though we don't want it to.